# What's the best way to deal with images in a Java web app: storing in Blob fields or just its paths?

Tags: java, image, web, blob

The new web Java app I'm working on will have to store many images. What's the best option: storing then in BLOB fields in MySQL or just their paths (and then putting the images on a specific drive)?
Will BLOB choice make my application too slow?

Comment: Have you done any measuring?

Comment: Blobs are difficult to deal with and typically require special code to process the result set.  Also, `java.nio` is REALLY fast.  Most CMS use filesystem for images and other binary data.  I would follow their lead...

Comment: Will you remember to back up the filesystem in sync with the database?

Answer (score 1):

Over the years I've done both and I've found there's generally not much in it.

Programatically blobs easier to deal with as they are just a `byte[]` in JPA and well supported. The downside is that you have to handle most of the delivery of the image to the client yourself and you risk your code becoming a performance bottle neck. If you let the web sever handle sending images you make use of highly optimized code and your application can get on with dealing with the business logic.